# Changing look of meshc plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, mesh, contour

I have some code that creates a random landscape and contour, but I can't find out to control the colours, shading, contour line colors, number of contour lines etc. Nothign I've found googling helps. Here's the code:

```
function create_landscape()

Lx=1;
dx=0.01;
x=0:dx:Lx;
nx=length(x);
Ly=5;
dy=0.01;
y=0:dy:Ly;
ny=length(y);

[mgx,mgy]=meshgrid(x,y);
landscape=zeros(ny ,nx);
nhills=100;
maxh=1;
maxw=0.03;
maxl=maxw*Ly/Lx;
xbuf=0.1;
ybuf=0.1;
pd=makedist('Normal','mu',0,'sigma',1e-5*exp(-1));

for i=1:nhills
    center=[xbuf+(Lx-2*xbuf)*rand,ybuf+(Ly-2*ybuf)*rand];
    w=rand*maxw;
    l=rand*maxl;
    sign=(-1)^(ceil(2*rand));
    h=random(pd)*maxh/1e-5;
    landscape=landscape+hill(mgx,mgy,sign*h,center,w,l);
end

m=meshc(mgx,mgy,landscape);
axis([-0.2 Lx+0.2 -0.2 Ly+0.2 -maxh*1.5 maxh*3])
grid off
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
hold off;

end

function fx=hill(x,y,h,center,w,l)
fx=h*exp(-(x-center(1)).*(x-center(1))/w^2).*exp(-(y-center(2)).*(y-center(2))/l^2);
end
```

Any idea how I can change how it looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color using the function [colormap](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html)

Instead of using the mesh function, you can use the `surfc(...,...,...,'EdgeColor','none')` function if you want a plain surface.

If you want to create a landscape with more lines, you will have to change your parameter `dx` and `dy`

The `colormap('pink')` would give you the following result (you can also define your own colormap), on the left the function surfc and on the right the function meshc.

[image]